# compare matrix elements with corresponding blocks in another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare-and-swap

I have a 4*4 matrix like X and a 2*2 matrix like A.

```
 X= x11   x21   x31   x41          A=   1    0
    x12   x22   x32   x42               0    1
    x13   x23   x33   x43
    x14   x24   x34   x44
```

I divided X to four 2*2 blocks with the code below:

```
  Y=X;
  sx=size(X);
  mask=logical([1 1;1 1]);
  for i=1:2:sx(1)
      for j=1:2:sx(2)
         px=X(i:i+1,j:j+1);
     end 
 end
```

Now I have to compare each element of matrix A with corresponding block of matrix  X.

```
 If the first element of matrix A is zero, then x11 should be lower than x22.
 if not, I should swap them with each other.


 If the first element of matrix A is one ,then x11 should be greater than x22.
 if not,I should swap them with each other.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to add this code in you for loop.

```
if A(1,1)==0 & px(2,2)>px(1,1)
    [px(1,1), px(2,2)] = deal(px(2,2),px(1,1));
elseif A(1,1)==1 & px(2,2)<px(1,1)
    [px(1,1), px(2,2)] = deal(px(2,2),px(1,1));
end
```

---

*PS. I think there is a better way of selecting a sub-matrix from a larger one, but cant think of it now.*